# Installing multiple packages in Ansible

Tags: ansible

I have this task in Ansible:

```
- name: Install mongodb
  yum:
    name:
    - "mongodb-org-{{ mongodb_version }}"
    - "mongodb-org-server-{{ mongodb_version }}"
    - "mongodb-org-mongos-{{ mongodb_version }}"
    - "mongodb-org-shell-{{ mongodb_version }}"
    - "mongodb-org-tools-{{ mongodb_version }}"
    state: present
  notify: Restart mongodb
```

Is there a way I can indicate the version without having to use a loop like this? What is a more "elegant" way of writing this?

```
- name: Install mongodb
  yum:
    name: "{{ item }}-{{ mongodb_version }}"
    state: present
    loop:
    - mongodb-org-server
    - mongodb-org-mongos
    - mongodb-org-shell
    - mongodb-org-tools
  notify: Restart mongodb
```

Comment: I doubt there is any better solution. Maybe if you make the list of packages as a variable and then use the variable in `name`. It would at least make the code cleaner and separate logic from variables and constants.

Comment: To make it a little bit clear, I would use the var folder and create a var that holds a list of the needed mongodb's, and call that var, so your overall tasks will be much more clear when looking at it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Make this into an [Ansible Role](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_reuse_roles.html) called `mongo`, resulting in the directory structure:

```
playbook.yml
roles
|-- mongo
|  |-- defaults
|  |    |-- main.yml
|  |
|  |-- tasks
|  |    |-- main.yml
|  |
|  |-- handlers
|  |    |-- main.yml
```

Add the required MongoDB packages and version into the default variables file `roles/mongo/defaults/main.yml`:

```
mongo_version: 4.0
mongo_packages:
- mongodb-org-server
- mongodb-org-mongos
- mongodb-org-shell
- mongodb-org-tools
```

Re-write the task in the `roles/mongo/tasks/main.yml` file:

```
- name: Install mongodb
  yum:
    name: "{{ item }}-{{ mongo_version }}"
    state: present
  with_items: "{{ mongo_packages }}"
  notify: Restart mongodb
```

Add your handler logic to restart MongoDB in the file `roles/mongo/handlers/main.yml`.

Write a Playbook called `playbook.yml` that calls the role.

```
---
- hosts: all
  roles:
  - mongo
```

Comment: using `with_items` means apt or yum will be called for each package in the list independently.

Answer (score 45):

To my surprise **I didn't find the *simplest* solution** in all the answers, *so here it is*. Referring to the question title `Installing multiple packages in Ansible` this is (using the [yum module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/yum_module.html)):

```
- name: Install MongoDB
  yum:
    name:
      - mongodb-org-server
      - mongodb-org-mongos
      - mongodb-org-shell
      - mongodb-org-tools 
    state: latest
    update_cache: true
```

Or with the [apt module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/apt_module.html):

```
- name: Install MongoDB
  apt:
    pkg:
      - mongodb-org-server
      - mongodb-org-mongos
      - mongodb-org-shell
      - mongodb-org-tools 
    state: latest
    update_cache: true
```

Both modules support inline lists!

*The second part of your question* is **how to integrate specific version numbers into the package lists**. No problem - simply remove the `state: latest` (since using specific version numbers together with `state: latest` would raise errors) and add the version numbers to the package names using a preceding `=` like this:

```
- name: Install MongoDB
  yum:
    name:
      - mongodb-org-server=1:3.6.3-0centos1.1
      - mongodb-org-mongos=1:3.6.3-0centos1.1
      - mongodb-org-shell=1:3.6.3-0centos1.1
      - mongodb-org-tools=1:3.6.3-0centos1.1 
    update_cache: true
```

You could also optimize further and template the version numbers. In this case don't forget to add quotation marks :)

Comment: This is the right answer. I don't know what the others are going on about.

Comment: Either I misunderstood the question or this does not actually answer the it.

Comment: Well the answer is about installing multiple packages in Ansible - what do you actually mean by "does not answer it"?

Answer (score 14):

Some people have mentioned syntax that allows passing a list, but you don't need to special-case your code for `apt` or `yum`. Here is the command that uses the generic package manager module:

```
- name: Install packages
  become: yes
  package:
    name:
      - tmux
      - rsync
      - zsh
      - rsync
      - wget
    state: present
```

(Or `state: latest`.) This feature is only [documented](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/modules/package_module.html) for Ansible 2.9, so it may be new.

Answer (score 7):

I think this is best way, but as the package names should not be hard coded, it is preferred to keep in vars/main.yml
e.g

```
mongodb_version: 5
packages:
  - "mongodb-org-shell-{{ mongodb_version }}"
  - "mongodb-org-server-{{ mongodb_version }}"
```

Call this inside your playbook as

```
- name: Install mongodb packages
  yum: name={{ item }}
       state=latest
  with_items: "{{ packages}}"
```

Comment: The `yum` module would complain if I use a loop to install the packages.

Answer (score 4):

Now yum module direct accept array of packages like this

```
  vars:
    pkgs:
      - screen
      - rubygems
      - ksh
      - strace

  tasks:
  - name: Install pre-requisite packages
    yum: name={{ pkgs }} state=installed
```

Answer (score 2):

A more elegant way, which doesn't keep re-checking each and every package if installed every time the script is run is to use something like this:

In `vars/main.yml` or similar:

```
  packages_to_install:
    - mongodb-org-server
    - mongodb-org-mongos
    - mongodb-org-shell
    - mongodb-org-tools
```

In `tasks/main.yml` or similar:

```
  - name: "Get installed packages"
    yum:
      list: "installed"
    register: installed_packages

  - name: "Install missing packages"
    package: 
      state: "present"
      name: "{{ item }}"
    with_items: "{{ packages_to_install | difference(installed_packages | json_query('results[*].name')) }}"
```

Essentially this checks what is already installed and only installs missing packages. Counter-intuitively this is faster. You can also use `dnf` instead of `yum`.