# Use ansible package module to work with apt and homebrew

Tags: macos, ansible, homebrew

I have two problems with creating playbook that works on linux and on macOS.

I have many steps like this one in my playbooks:

```
- name: install something
  package:
    name: [something_1, something_2, ...]
    state: present
  become: yes
```

It works nice for apt and yum, but when I tried to run this on macOS, homebrew complains:

`Running Homebrew as root is extremely dangerous and no longer supported.`

I couldn't find elegant way of fixing that in many places. Copy all tasks and use **when** clause seems overwhelming to me. Probably I could use become_user variable set to root/local_user dependent on distribution, but that's a lot changes too.

Second problem is with head-only formula (homebrew packages that can be installed only with --head flag). What if something_2 need to be installed with this flag? Again I could copy task and change **package** module to **homebrew** but that's a lot boilerplate.

Any help?

Comment: Have you tried the homebrew module: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/homebrew_module.html

Comment: @dejdej I tried and it works, but it forces me to duplicate every step like the one presented in question.

Comment: Ok , it's not recommended but you could also try:`sudo chown -R \`whoami\` /usr/local` + `brew doctor` also as side note: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Security/Conceptual/System_Integrity_Protection_Guide/ConfiguringSystemIntegrityProtection/ConfiguringSystemIntegrityProtection.html

Comment: Have you considered using `become: "{{ ansible_os_family != 'Darwin' }}"` (or even perhaps `become_user: "{{ the_actual_user if ansible_os_family == 'Darwin' else 'root' }}"`)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want a single set of tasks that flexible enough for for multiple Linux
package managers and macOS brew, the choice is either more logic or more
duplication.

These three patterns should help. They still have repetition and
boilerplate code, but that's the territory we're in with Ansible plays
for cross-platform.

1. Declare `become: yes` (root) globally for Linux only
2. Address packages that need platform-specific treatment as-needed with `when`

   - This might be `--head` for `brew`, or setting up a PPA for `apt`, etc
3. Map package name discrepancies with variables

   - For example: `brew install ncurses`, `apt install libncurses5-dev`, and `dnf install ncurses-devel` are all the same library.

#### 1) Declare `become: yes` (root) globally for Linux only

For Linux hosts, switching to root for installation is the intended behavior.
For macOS a la Homebrew, installing as root is not good. So, we need `become: no` (`false`) when using `brew`, and `become: yes` (`true`) otherwise (for
Linux).

In your example the `become` directive is nested inside each task ("step"). To
prevent duplication, invoke `become` at a higher lexical scope, before the tasks
start. The subsequent tasks will then inherit the state of `become`, which is
set based on a conditional expression.

Unfortunately a variable for `become` at the root playbook scope will be
undefined and throw an error before the first task is run:

```yaml
# playbook.yml
- name: Demo
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  # This works
  become: True
  # This doesn't - the variable is undefined
  become: "{{ False if ansible_pkg_mgr == 'brew' else True }}"
  # Nor does this - also undefined
  become: "{{ False if ansible_os_family == 'Darwin' else True }}"

  tasks:
    # ...
```

To fix this, we can store the tasks in another file and [import](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_reuse_includes.html#including-and-importing-task-files) them, or
wrap the tasks in a [block](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/user_guide/playbooks_blocks.html). Either of these patterns will provide
a chance to declare `become` with our custom variable value in time for the
tasks to pick it up:

```yaml
# playbook.yml
---
- name: Demo
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  vars:
    # This variable gives us a boolean for deciding whether or not to become
    # root. It cascades down to any subsequent tasks unless overwritten.
    should_be_root:  "{{ true if ansible_pkg_mgr != 'brew' else false }}"

    # It could also be based on the OS type, but since brew is the main cause
    # it's probably better this way.
    # should_be_root: "{{ False if ansible_os_family == 'Darwin' else True }}"

  tasks:
    # Import the tasks from another file, which gives us a chance to pass along
    # a `become` context with our variable:
    - import_tasks: test_tasks.yml
      become: "{{ should_be_root }}"

    # Wrapping the tasks in a block will also work:
    - block:
      - name: ncurses is present
        package:
          name: [libncurses5-dev, libncursesw5-dev]
          state: present
      - name: cmatrix is present
        package:
          name: cmatrix
          state: present
      become: "{{ should_be_root }}"
```

Now there is a single logic check for `brew` and a single `before` directive
(depending on which task pattern above is used). All tasks will be executed as
the root user, unless the package manager in use is `brew`.

#### 2) Address packages that need platform-specific treatment as-needed with `when`

The [Package Module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/package_module.html) is a great convenience but it's quite limited. By
itself it only works for ideal scenarios; meaning, a package that doesn't
require any special treatment or flags from the underlying package manager. All
it can do is pass the literal string of the package to install, the `state`, and
an optional parameter to force use of a specific package manager executable.

Here's an example that installs `wget` with a nice short task and only becomes
verbose to handle `ffmpeg`'s special case when installed with `brew`:

```yaml
# playbook.yml
# ...
  tasks:
    # wget is the same among package managers, nothing to see here
    - name: wget is present
      when: ansible_pkg_mgr != 'brew'
      package:
        name: wget
        state: present

    # This will only run on hosts that do not use `brew`, like linux
    - name: ffmpeg is present
      when: ansible_pkg_mgr != 'brew'
      package:
        name: ffmpeg
        state: present

    # This will only run on hosts that use `brew`, i.e. macOS
    - name: ffmpeg is present (brew)
      when: ansible_pkg_mgr == 'brew'
      homebrew:
        name: ffmpeg
        # head flag
        state: head
        # --with-chromaprint --with-fdk-aac --with-etc-etc
        install_options: with-chromaprint, with-fdk-aac, with-etc-etc
```

The play above would produce this output for `ffmpeg` against a Linux box:

```
TASK [youtube-dl : ffmpeg is present] ******************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [youtube-dl : ffmpeg is present (brew)] ***********************************
skipping: [localhost]
```

#### 3) Map package name discrepancies with variables

This isn't specifically part of your question but it's likely to come up next.

The [Package Module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/package_module.html) docs also mention:

> Package names also vary with package manager; this module will not "translate"
> them per distro. For example libyaml-dev, libyaml-devel.

So, we're on our own to handle cases where the same software uses different
names between package manager platforms. This is quite common.

There are multiple patterns for this, such as:

- Use [separate variable files](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/include_vars_module.html#examples) for each OS/distro and import them
  conditionally
- [Use a role with its own variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54944080/installing-multiple-packages-in-ansible#answer-58644752)
- Use the same package manager across platforms, such as [Homebrew](https://docs.brew.sh/Homebrew-on-Linux) or
  [Conda](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/)
- Compile everything from source via git

None of them are very pleasant. Here is an approach using a [role](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_reuse_roles.html). Roles do
involve more boilerplate and directory juggling, but in exchange they provide
modularity and a local variable environment. When a set of tasks in a role
requires more finagling to get right, it doesn't end up polluting other task
sets.

```yaml
# playbook.yml
---
- name: Demo
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  roles:
    - cmatrix

# roles/cmatrix/defaults/main.yml
---
ncurses:
  default:
    - ncurses
  # Important: these keys need to exactly match the name of package managers for
  # our logic to hold up
  apt:
    - libncurses5-dev
    - libncursesw5-dev
  brew:
    - pkg-config
    - ncurses

# roles/cmatrix/tasks/main.yml
---
- name: cmatix and its dependencies are present
  become: "{{ should_be_root }}"
  block:
    - name: ncurses is present
      package:
        name: '{{ item }}'
        state: latest
      loop: "{{ ncurses[ansible_pkg_mgr] | default(ncurses['default']) }}"

    - name: cmatrix is present
      when: ansible_pkg_mgr != 'brew'
      package:
        name: cmatrix
        state: present
```

The task for `ncurses` looks for an array of items to loop through keyed by the
corresponding package manager. If the package manager being used is not defined
in the variable object, a Jinja default filter is employed to reference the
`default` value we set.

With this pattern, adding support for another package manager or additional
dependencies simply involves updating the variable object:

```yaml
# roles/cmatrix/defaults/main.yml
---
ncurses:
  default:
    - ncurses
  apt:
    - libncurses5-dev
    - libncursesw5-dev
    # add a new dependency for Debian
    - imaginarycurses-dep
  brew:
    - pkg-config
    - ncurses
  # add support for Fedora
  dnf:
    - ncurses-devel
```

#### Combining everything into a real play

Here's a full example covering all three aspects. The playbook has two roles
that each use the correct `become` value based on a single variable. It also
incorporates an special cases for `cmatrix` and `ffmpeg` when installed with
`brew`, and handles alternate names for ncurses between package managers.

```yaml
# playbook.yml
---
- name: Demo
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  vars:
    should_be_root:  "{{ true if ansible_pkg_mgr != 'brew' else false }}"
  roles:
    - cmatrix
    - youtube-dl
```

```yaml
# roles/cmatrix/defaults/main.yml
ncurses:
  default:
    - ncurses
  apt:
    - libncurses5-dev
    - libncursesw5-dev
  brew:
    - pkg-config
    - ncurses
  dnf:
    - ncurses-devel
```

```yaml
# roles/cmatrix/tasks/main.yml
---
- name: cmatrix and dependencies are present
  # A var from above, in the playbook
  become: "{{ should_be_root }}"

  block:
    - name: ncurses is present
      package:
        name: '{{ item }}'
        state: latest
      # Get an array of the correct package names to install from the map in our
      # default variables file
      loop: "{{ ncurses[ansible_pkg_mgr] | default(ncurses['default']) }}"

    # Install as usual if this is not a brew system
    - name: cmatrix is present
      when: ansible_pkg_mgr != 'brew'
      package:
        name: cmatrix
        state: present
    # If it is a brew system, use this instead
    - name: cmatrix is present (brew)
      when: ansible_pkg_mgr == 'brew'
      homebrew:
        name: cmatrix
        state: head
        install_options: with-some-option
```

```yaml
# roles/youtube-dl/tasks/main.yml
---
- name: youtube-dl and dependencies are present
  become: "{{ should_be_root }}"

  block:
    - name: ffmpeg is present
      when: ansible_pkg_mgr != 'brew'
      package:
        name: ffmpeg
        state: latest
    - name: ffmpeg is present (brew)
      when: ansible_pkg_mgr == 'brew'
      homebrew:
        name: ffmpeg
        state: head
        install_options: with-chromaprint, with-fdk-aac, with-etc-etc

    - name: atomicparsley is present
      package:
        name: atomicparsley
        state: latest

    - name: youtube-dl is present
      package:
        name: youtube-dl
        state: latest
```

**The result for Ubuntu:**

```
$ ansible-playbook demo.yml
[WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available. Note that
the implicit localhost does not match 'all'

PLAY [Demo] ********************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *********************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [cmatrix : ncurses is present] ********************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=libncurses5-dev)
ok: [localhost] => (item=libncursesw5-dev)

TASK [cmatrix : cmatrix is present] ********************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [cmatrix : cmatrix is present (brew)] *************************************
skipping: [localhost]

TASK [youtube-dl : ffmpeg is present] ******************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [youtube-dl : ffmpeg is present (brew)] ***********************************
skipping: [localhost]

TASK [youtube-dl : atomicparsley is present] ***********************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [youtube-dl : youtube-dl is present] **************************************
ok: [localhost]

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=6    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=2    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: Glad to help! Cheers